# Sum of random variables and expectation ... difference?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

$C_j = 1/s_j \sum_{i=1}^n w_iJ_i^j$.

$w_i$ is some (real) number. $J_i^j$ is a 0-1 random variable and the P($J_i^j = 1)= p_i^j$.

$l_j = 1/s_j \sum_{i:[n]} w_i p_i^j$. This is a sum over all $i$. (Both summations are over all $i$. So there are $n$ $i$'s). Intuitively, $i$ are the number of tasks to be completed.

What is the difference between $l_j$ and $C_j$? If so, what is it?

Comment: What is $s_j$? Is it the sum of all J?

Comment: fair question. $s_j$ can be thought of as either speed or capacity of link $j$. It is a constant number for each edge or link $j$.

Comment: In that case, I think yo need to give a "preamble" describing the context. It sould like this is part of some network analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking solely at your formulation and taking $s_j$ to be a fixed, real number >0:

The main difference between $C_j$ and $l_j$ is that the former is a *random variable* while the latter is the *expected value* of $C_j$. By linearity of expectation:

$E[C_j]=E[1/s_j \sum_{i=1}^n w_iJ_i^j]=\frac{1}{s_j}E[\sum_{i=1}^n w_iJ_i^j]=\frac{1}{s_j}\sum_{i=1}^n w_iE[J_i^j]$

Since $J_i^j$ is an indicator variable with $P(J_i^j = 1)= p_i^j, P(J_i^j = 0)= 1-p_i^j$, we get: $E[J_i^j]=p_i^j\rightarrow E[C_j]=\frac{1}{s_j}\sum_{i=1}^n w_iE[J_i^j]=1/s_j \sum_{i:[n]} w_i p_i^j =l_j$